# Finding common outputs of 3 functions

Tags: python

I have 3 functions.These are

```
A(n) = n(n+1)/2
B(n) = n(3n-1)/2
C(n) = n(2n-1)
```

Their first common output and indexes are:

```
A(285)=B(165)=C(143)=40755
```

I need second one,so I tried this:

```
 def equation1(x):
    return x*(x+1)/2

def equation2(x):
    return x*((3*x)-1)/2

def equation3(x):
    return x*((2*x)-1)

for i in range(144,30000):
    x = equation3(i)
    for a in range(i,2*i):
            y = equation2(a)
            if(x==y):
                for b in range(a,2*a):
                    z = equation1(b)
                    if(x==y==z):
                        print("Term =" + str(x))
                        print("A" + str(b))
                        print("B" + str(a))
                        print("C" + str(i))
```

But it takes too much time to find it.How can I handle this in an easier way?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all three functions are increasing? In other words, are you sure that if `m > n` then `A(m) > A(n)` and similary for `B` and `C`?

Comment: @RoryDaulton  it is,all of them are increasing and they won't get negative inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all three functions are increasing for positive values, you can write a loop that increases the number with the smallest value at each iteration:

```
a = b = c = 1
eq_a = equation1(a)
eq_b = equation2(b)
eq_c = equation3(c)

while True:
  if eq_a == eq_b and eq_b == eq_c:
    print("Found {}, {}, {}, result={}".format(a,b,c,eq_a))
  if eq_a <= eq_b and eq_a <= eq_c:
    a += 1
    eq_a = equation1(a)
  elif eq_b <= eq_a and eq_b <= eq_c:
    b += 1
    eq_b = equation2(b)
  elif eq_c <= eq_a and eq_c <= eq_b:
    c += 1
    eq_c = equation3(c)
  else:
    print("Should never be here")
    assert(False);
```

Test run:

```
Found 1, 1, 1, result=1
Found 285, 165, 143, result=40755
Found 55385, 31977, 27693, result=1533776805
Found 10744501, 6203341, 5372251, result=57722156241751
```

Comment: I had the same idea--this is a good algorithm if the number of functions is known before doing the programming.  You could speed this up and prevent excess function evaluations if you update the `eq` variables each time you update the indices. In other words, remove the `eq_a=` lines at the top if the `while` loop and add `eq_a=` just after `a += 1`, etc. Of course, you need one preliminary evaluation before entering the `while` loop.